# Which performance metrics for highly imbalanced multiclass dataset?

Tags: classification, unbalanced-classes, model-evaluation, auc, precision-recall

I have a dataset with 5 classes. About 98% of the dataset belong to class 5. Classes 1-4 share equally about 2% of the dataset. However, it is highly important, that classes 1-4 are correctly classified.

The accuracy is not a good measure of performance for my task. I found lots of information on metrics for imbalanced binary classification tasks but not on multiclass problems.

Which performance metrics should I use for such a task?

- TP, TN, FP, FN
- Precision
- Sensitivity
- Specificity
- F-score
- ROC-AUC (micro, macro, samples, weighted)

Comment: https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6349/profusion-of-threads-on-imbalanced-data-can-we-merge-deem-canonical-any

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**For unbalanced classes, I would suggest to go with Weighted F1-Score or Average AUC/Weighted AUC**

Let's first see F1-Score for binary classification.

**The F1-score gives a larger weight to lower numbers.**

For example,

- when Precision is 100% and Recall is 0%, the F1-score will be 0%, not 50%.
- When let us say, we have Classifier A with precision=recall=80%, and Classifier B has precision=60%, recall=100%.
  Arithmetically, the mean of the precision and recall is the same for both models. But when we use F1’s harmonic mean formula,
  the score for Classifier A will be 80%, and for Classifier B it will be only 75%.
  Model B’s low precision score pulled down its F1-score.

Now, come to the **Mutliclass Classification**

Let us suppose we have the five classes, class_1, class_2, class_3, class_4, class_5

and the model is having the following results for each class.

[image]

**Formula for precision for each class**  =  `(True Positive for class)/(Count of predicted Positive for that class)`

e.g. precision for class_1 = (True Positive for class_1)/(Count of Predicted of class_1)

**Formula for Recall for each class**  =  `(True Positive for class)/(Actual Positive for that class)`

e.g. precision for class_1 = (True Positive for class_1)/(Total instances of class_1)

**Formula for F1:** F1 is the geometric mean of Precision and Recall i.e.

```
F1 = 2*(Precision*Recall)/(Precision+Recall)

Macro-F1 = Average(Class_1_F1 + Class_2_F1 + Class_3_F1 + Class_4_F1 + Class_5_F1)

Macro-Precision = Average(Class_1_Precision + Class_2_Precision + Class_3_Precision + Class_4_Precision + Class_5_Precision)

Macro-Recall = Average(Class_1_Recall + Class_2_Recall + Class_3_Recall + Class_4_Recall + Class_5_Recall)
```

**Problem with Macro calculation: When averaging the macro-F1, we gave equal weights to each class.**

**Weighted F1 Score:**

We don’t have to do that: in weighted-average F1-score, or weighted-F1,
we weight the F1-score of each class by the number of samples from that class.

```
Weighted F1 Score = (N1*Class_1_F1 + N2*Class_2_F1 + N3*Class_3_F1 + N4*Class_4_F1 + N5*Class_5_F1)/(N1 + N2 + N3 + N4 + N5)
```

References: https://towardsdatascience.com/multi-class-metrics-made-simple-part-ii-the-f1-score-ebe8b2c2ca1

Comment: Just for the record: Medium articles are not credible sources. (I am not down-voting this post or anything like that, but I have seen "bad" Medium articles from experienced users; so be careful about them.)

Comment: Thanks for that, i checked the profile of the writer, he is a P.hD student and have good experience with Data Science. Apart from this, I am a Data Scientist, I have used this Metric for our models evaluation.

Comment: Why is giving equal weights to each class in Macro F1 a bad thing? For example, Let us assume that class one is the majority class, and Class_1_F1 is the highest as well. wouldn't this mean Weighted F1 is represents F1 of the majority class 1? But we want a metric that represents the minority classes, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Precision, recall, F1, ROC/AUC, and other metrics like specificity/sensitivity that you mentioned can be good for multi-class imbalanced metrics. If you want to emphasize the undersampled classes, use macro weighting (arithmetic average). If not, use micro average, which is weighted by number of samples.

Another metric I don't see people often talking about is Cohen's Kappa. I like to think of it like accuracy, but taking into account the "no information rate" or random guessing baseline. It will give you a score similar to accuracy, though I believe it has some flaws in certain situations. In general, I've found Cohen's Kappa to work well.

Others include the litany of metrics listed on Wikipedia's [confusion matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confusion_matrix) page, such as Matthew's correlation coefficient (MCC) and others.